# AppDomain unloaded issue with service bus version 2.6.5

Tags: appdomain, servicebus

We have multiple projects that are making use of the service bus library. We are currently using v2.6.5 at the moment and we've been getting several warnings for unit tests that calls to the code in the library. This is the warning message:

System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

And we would get it everytime we invoke this method: TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName)

This warning will not appear if we use the built-in Visual Studio test runner (2012/2015) and it would appear if we opt to use the MSTest runner via the .runsettings file.

It will also not appear if I update my service bus to version 3.0.0 and above but that is not possible because we were having a separate issues with them so the only option now is the stick to version 2.6.5 and try to fix those warnings.

Any idea what could be wrong? If you guys need additional information I'm happy to come up with a simple project that is able to reproduce the warning.